# Python Insert vars with commas into MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, database

I have variable value with comma (ex. var='some text, with comma')
How to INSERT this whole text (with comma) into one column?

My code doesn't work:

```
c.execute("""INSERT INTO resumes (var) VALUES (%s)""",(var_with_comma))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the query parameters defined as an *iterable* (`tuple` in your case), replace:

```
c.execute("""INSERT INTO resumes (var) VALUES (%s)""",(var_with_comma))
```

with:

```
c.execute("""INSERT INTO resumes (var) VALUES (%s)""",(var_with_comma, ))
```

No other special handled needed - the database driver would detect that the query parameter is a string and would handle the quoting and escaping appropriately.

Comment: what if i had more than one var in INSERT request? c.execute("""INSERT INTO resumes (var, var2, var3) VALUES (%s)""",(var_with_comma, var_without_comma, var_with_comma))

Comment: @KonstantinRusanov nope, add a placeholder for every query parameter. In this case: `INSERT INTO resumes (var, var2, var3) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)`

Comment: Sorry, c.execute("""INSERT INTO resumes (var, var2, var3) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""",(var_with_comma, var_without_comma, var_with_comma)) - but it's doesn't work, returns TypeError: 'DataError' object is not callable

Comment: No, that line will not produce that error.  Try it again.

Answer (score -1):

@KonstantinRusanov

It seems that a your additional question have not been resolved.

Did you try the named parameter as follows?

```py
c.execute("""
    INSERT INTO resumes 
        (var, var2, var3) 
    VALUES 
        (%(var)s, %(var2)s, %(var3)s)
""",
{
    "var": "<value_for_var>",
    "var2": "<value_for_var2>",
    "var3": "<value_for_var3>",
})
```